# set feature image without show it in the post

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to Set featured image but I don't like it to figure into my post 
just I want see it in my home page as an ad to my post 
how can i do it ? it is from my single.php
this is my single.php

```
<?php
    /**
     * @package WordPress
     * @subpackage Wheels
     */
    $is_boxed = school_time_get_option( 'single-post-is-boxed', false );
    if ( $is_boxed ) {
        get_header( 'boxed' );
    } else {
        get_header();
    }
    ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'templates/title' ); ?>
    <div class="<?php echo school_time_class( 'main-wrapper' ) ?>">
        <div class="<?php echo school_time_class( 'container' ); ?>">
            <?php if ( school_time_get_option( 'single-post-sidebar-left', false ) ): ?>
                <div class="<?php echo school_time_class( 'sidebar' ) ?>">
                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="<?php echo school_time_class( 'content' ) ?>">
                    <?php get_template_part( 'templates/content-single' ); ?>
                </div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div class="<?php echo school_time_class( 'content' ) ?>">
                    <?php get_template_part( 'templates/content-single' ); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="<?php echo school_time_class( 'sidebar' ) ?>">
                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    if ( $is_boxed ) {
        get_footer( 'boxed' );
    } else {
        get_footer();
    }
    ?>
```

and this is index.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Wheels
 */
get_header();
?>
<?php get_template_part( 'templates/title' ); ?>
<div class="<?php echo school_time_class( 'main-wrapper' ) ?>">
 <div class="<?php echo school_time_class( 'container' ) ?>">
  <div class="<?php echo school_time_class( 'content' ) ?>">
   <?php if ( have_posts() ): ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <?php get_template_part( 'templates/content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php else: ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'none' ); ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <div class="<?php echo school_time_class( 'pagination' ) ?>">
    <?php school_time_pagination(); ?>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="<?php echo school_time_class( 'sidebar' ) ?>">
   <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Check your code for `content-single.php` under your `templates` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under templates directory there will be content-single.php located...check it for the img tag and comment the img tag and then try....
If it doesn't work post the content-single.php file code.

Comment: I have already two days that I am trying to find a solution µ
thank you very much

Comment: ¨Please do you know how to add text in the apparent part of the post in the homepage without being displayed in the post?  @Akshit Ahuja

Comment: please post the code of index.php...after that i can help you.

Comment: i post it 
can you help me please ?

Comment: In templates directory there will be content.php located and from there all the contents are coming of the post that you see on homepage...check for it and do changes there as you want...

Comment: and If I put the post  in a new page and not in the home page  ?

Comment: can you be more descriptive?? I can't understand what you want to say..

Comment: it's ok 
i find a solution , it's about adding an Excerpt to each post 
but i can't make a line break 
do you have any idea how to do it in the excerpt ??

Answer (score 0):

You may try this plugin & then Edit your post & below featured image, you will get the option to hide/show.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-featured-image/

Comment: i think we should not add extra plugins if we can do it from code..because more plugins affects the speed and loading time of our wordpress website.

Comment: But for the custom code you to take care of WordPress regular updates.